# Disable checkbox if the value is already in databse

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am having trouble disabling the checkbox if the value is already in DB.

I have tablename `staff_availability` and it has column `from` the datatype is `time`. I have multiple values for `from` (e.g. `09:00:00`, `10:00:00` and so on...) It works already but one thing is if disabled I want to make the it color red and add some text into the label like "09:00 AM is already scheduled. Here is my code:

```
include 'dbconfig.php';
$upload_dir = 'uploads/';
$id = $_SESSION['stfid'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM staff_availability WHERE stfid = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$timelists[] = $row['fro'];
}
}
else {
    $timelists[] = '';
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-info">
    <input id="checkbox-15" type="checkbox" name="timelist[]" value="09:00:00" <?php echo (in_array("09:00:00", $timelists) ? "disabled='disabled'" : "") ?>>
    <label for="checkbox-15">
        09:00 AM - 10:00 AM
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-info">
    <input id="checkbox-15" type="checkbox" name="timelist[]" value="10:00:00" <?php echo (in_array("10:00:00", $timelists) ? "disabled='disabled'" : "") ?>>
    <label for="checkbox-15">
        10:00 AM - 11:00 AM
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-info">
    <input id="checkbox-15" type="checkbox" name="timelist[]" value="11:00:00" <?php echo (in_array("11:00:00", $timelists) ? "disabled='disabled'" : "") ?>>
    <label for="checkbox-15">
        11:00 AM - 12:00 PM
    </label>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

```
else {
    $timelists[] = '';
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: @jrswgtr is right i cant even read this :o

Comment: What's are the values of `$timelists[]`?

Comment: hello, I figured it out already check my code above. and one more thing is if disabled  I want to make it color red and add some text into it.